# Возвращение данных

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Сделал передачу данных через функцию, jquery .ajax() к php файлу. Но как отослать результат назад из php файла, и как ловить его в jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращаются данные обычным **echo $data** или **echo json_encode($data)**. Принимаются данные в **success**

```
$.ajax({
    // другие параметры
    success: function(data){
        // data - содержит ответ с сервера
    }
});
```

Comment: а со стороны php, как данные отдать. Через return?

Comment: через echo

Comment: Я же написал - **echo**.

Comment: Не заметил, простите)